# How to forward with GET parameters?

Tags: php, symfony

How to forward with `GET` parameters?

I have two actions in same controller. I do some magic in the first action, and if all goes well, I want it to forward to the other one, but with `GET` parameters created in the first one.

What I have now is this:

```
return $this->forward('AppBundle:default:tracked', array(), array(
                    'tracking_code' =>  $tracking_code,
                    'company'       =>  $tp_company_name
            )));
```

Empty array in there because of a desperate effort to get it to work. [Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_forward) tells that second array is for the query parameters, but nothing really happens, so I must be doing something wrong.

The second action tries to get the parameters like this:

```
/**
* @Route("/tracked", name="tracked")
*/
public function trackedAction()
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    // If there is the required variables in the GET:
    if($request->query->has('tracking_code') && $request->query->has('company'))
```

But no, variables never get there it seems.

Reason I have this kind of setup, is that user can get into the `trackedAction` from another place as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the proper way to get your parameters in your second action would be to do like this :

```
return $this->forward('AppBundle:default:tracked', array(
                'tracking_code' =>  $tracking_code,
                'company'       =>  $tp_company_name
        )));
```

And your second action would be :

```
/**
* @Route("/tracked/{tracking_code}/{company}", name="tracked")
*/
public function trackedAction($tracking_code=null, $company=null)
{
    ...
}
```

I used the `$tracking_code = null` because you specified this could be accessed from another place, that maybe does not provide these parameters. This way it works for both of them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers mate! I've tried to use this kind of solution before and it always complained about the non existing variables or something alike, and therefore I discarded this one in this situation as well. Of course giving the variables null by default makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2):

The way that Symfony controller forwarding works is by duplicating the current the `Request` with the options that you pass and then re-dispatching it through the `HttpKernel` component. You can see this [in the code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L64). Because it's a sub-request, your second action is creating a `Request` from globals (i.e. `$_GET` etc.) which haven't changed.

The solution is to change your second action method signature to:

```
public function trackedAction(Request $request)
```

This means that the `$request` variable will be "local" to your action and will contain the variables you want.

In practice you should **always** pass the `Request` in to your actions this way as it makes your controllers a lot more testable and prevents strange issues like this.

Alternatively to all of the above, you could use a [redirect](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L80) instead which would do an HTTP redirect rather than just forwarding within the Symfony request system.